# Proof that a limit is a partial derivative

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I'm writing up several proofs for myself, all of which have a particular sticking point.

Essentially, I want to prove that for a function $f$ of two real variables, we have

$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x \;+\; h, \; y \;+\; h) \; - \; f(x, \; y \;+ \;h)}{h} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$.

When I've seen this crop up in textbooks and lecture notes (say, in the context of proving the multivariable chain rule), it's generally just been taken for granted, rather than proven.

Intuitively, how can we be sure that the function is sufficiently well behaved that having $y + h$ instead of $y$ in the second argument doesn't 'mess things up' and not allow this limit to be the partial derivative? And moreover, how could I give a rigorous proof of this?

Thanks all!

Comment: If $f$ is totally differentiable in $(x,y)$, everything is fine, as demonstrated by Ninad Munshi in their answer. However, if $f$ is only partially differentiable in $x$-direction, I think the claim is not true and the limit might not exist.

Comment: @amsmath total differentiability is not necessary, only that the partials exist.

Comment: @NinadMunshi No, that's definitely wrong. Have a look at my counterexample below Allawonder's answer. Both partials exist there. Actually, all partials exist.

Comment: @amsmath I see, you are right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A sufficient condition for the claim to be true is that $f'_x=\partial f/\partial x$ exists in a neighbourhood of $(x,y)$ and is continuous at $(x,y)$.

**Proof.** Since $f'_x$ exists, the mean value theorem for derivatives says that
$$
f(x+h,y+h) - f(x,y+h) = f'_x(x+\theta h, y+h) \cdot h
$$
for some $\theta \in [0,1]$ (which may depend on $h$).
So your quotient is
$$
\frac{f(x+h,y+h) - f(x,y+h)}{h} = f'_x(x+\theta h, y+h)
,
$$
which tends to $f'_x(x,y)$ as $h \to 0$, because of the assumption that $f'_x$ is continuous there.

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x+h,y+h)-f(x,y+h)}{h} = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x+h,y+h)-f(x,y)+f(x,y)-f(x,y+h)}{h}$$ $$ = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x+h,y+h)-f(x,y)}{h} - \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x,y+h)-f(x,y)}{h}$$ $$ = \sqrt{2}\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x+\frac{(\sqrt{2}h)}{\sqrt{2}},y+\frac{(\sqrt{2}h)}{\sqrt{2}})-f(x,y)}{(\sqrt{2}h)} - \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x,y+h)-f(x,y)}{h} $$ $$ = \sqrt{2}D_{(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})}f - \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} - \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$$

where $D_{\mathbf{u}}f$ is the directional derivative of $f$

Comment: The first term in the second step should be $f(x+h,y+h)$, not $f(x,y+h)$. And it should perhaps be mentioned that the evaluation of the directional derivative assumes that $f$ is differentiable at $(x,y)$.

Comment: @Ninad Thanks for your answer. Is there a way to do this without using the directional derivative, though? Often, textbooks present the chain rule before presenting gradient and the directional derivative, and so I think being able to do this without the directional derivative would be more satisfying.

Comment: @HansLundmark fixed. And that's okay, this proof obviously assumes enough niceness to work. Strictly speaking though, it does not require differentiability, only that the partials exist.

Comment: @M.Whyte sure just follow along any proof of the directional derivative (such as [this](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/DirectionalDeriv.aspx) one) and eventually they will prove that the definition of directional derivative is a dot product by some substitution. You can use that same substitution here.

Comment: @M.Whyte actually I see your point, they use the chain rule to justify the dot product. I will try to think of another way.

Comment: @M.Whyte I have added another proof, take a look to verify if it makes sense.

Comment: $x$ and $y$ are clearly fixed from the scratch. But what is $z$ in your very last argument? Your second proof is actually incorrect.

Comment: @amsmath I define $z = y+h$ and then I (attempted) to argue that if such a limit were to exist, then it would equal another limit where $z$ was fixed but $y$ varies.

Comment: Be careful. Actually, when you write $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$, you also have to specify, where this function is evaluated. Here, it's supposed to be $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y)$, but in your last line you have $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,z)$, but $z$ was only a dummy variable and not a fixed point. Something went wrong.

Comment: @amsmath In this case $z$ stops being the dummy variable after the interchange of limits. I guess I could be more precise and add a penalty function of the kind $\frac{|y-z|^2}{2\epsilon}$ as $\epsilon\to 0$ (in the so-called "doubling the variables" method) to force $y$ and $z$ to converge to the same variable.

Comment: More concrete: in your second step you move from $z\to y$ over to $y\to z$. This is of course invalid because $y$ is a fixed value.

Comment: @amsmath As confusing as it looks, the first $y$ and the second $y$ are not the same variable. You are right this is not wholly justified, and I think can be fixed as mentioned above.

Comment: Then please fix it. As it stands now, it's wrong. And BTW, in the first proof you don't have to normalize. It's also fine without normalization.

Comment: @NinadMunshi: This might already have been covered in your discussion with amsmath, but mere existence of partials is **not** enough to allow you to evaluate the directional derivative through the formula “gradient dot direction vector”, you need differentiability for that.

Answer (score -1):

There's no way anything could be messed up since *the second coordinate is always fixed.* It's only the first that's varying. That is, we're considering the change from the point $(x,y+h)$ to the point $(x+h,y+h).$ Throughout this change, the second coordinate is clearly fixed. Thus, it's not concerned with the limiting process at all. This is why we can be sure that the limit, if it exists, is indeed the derivative with respect to $x,$ *fixing $y.$* Thus, there's nothing more to justify than in the usual derivative. Hence, what you noticed about the books.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98157/discussion-on-answer-by-allawonder-proof-that-a-limit-is-a-partial-derivative).

Comment: Perhaps this has already been discussed enough, but I just wanted to say that I agree with @amsmath that this answer is completely wrong. The second coordinate $y+h$ is clearly **not** fixed with respect to $h$, and this must of course be carefully taken into account when you're taking the limit as $h \to 0$.